# Charset problem with xgettext & msgmerge

Tags: bash, gettext, xgettext

I'm trying to make a script to create a .po files from my sources files & merge it with the existing one so I don't have to redo the translation every time I update my website.

I'm basing my script on this blog post http://www.lxg.de/code/playing-with-xgettext

Here is what I'm trying to run :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    if [ -d "./locale/$1" ]
    then
        echo '' > "./locale/$1/msg_tmp.po"
        find . -type f -iname "*.php" | xgettext -j --from-code="utf-8" -o "./locale/$1/msg_tmp.po" -f -
        msgmerge -N "./locale/$1/msg.po" "./locale/$1/msg_tmp_iconv.po" > "./locale/$1/msg_new.po"
        mv "./locale/$1/msg_new.po" "./locale/$1/msg.po"
        rm "./locale/$1/msg_tmp.po"
        rm "./locale/$1/msg_tmp_iconv.po"
    else
        echo The directory locale/$1 does not exist
    fi
else
    echo Locale not specified
fi
```

The problem is with the msgmerge command, It complains about non ascii strings & invalid multibyte sequence.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your translator forgot to fill in the `Content-Type` header properly.

Comment: I have a similar issue now, I use xgettext in cmd to write a `.po` file but the header prints `charset=CHARSET` instead of `UTF-8´ although I use in my call `--from-code=UTF-8` is there a way to adjust the header without having to use File I/O, some xgettext extension to adjust the header ?

Comment: You can use `sed -i 's/charset=CHARSET/charset=UTF-8/g' yourdomain.po` to convert the PO files' charset.