# No charset indication in .pot file after a pygettext extraction

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character

After extracting messages from a python3 application, with

```
pygettext.py --default-domain=po_typo_purifier po_typo_purifier.py
```

I get a .pot file with this header line

> "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"

Then when I open it in poedit some chars (in this case no-break space, and narrow-no break space) are not correctly displayed. More over after creating the .po and .mo files, the programme displays translation for messages who have no such chars in them only. 
If I change charset=UTF-8 in the line above, then every thing is OK at runtime. 
My question is: "How to have the charset set to UTF-8 while extracting messages?"

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, the self-evident answer to your question is that *you need to tell the tool to do it.* First step: run `pygettext.py --help` to see if there’s a flag for that. There isn’t, unfortunately, and [a quick look at the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/i18n/pygettext.py) reveals that

1. `pygettext.py` actually defaults to UTF-8 in Python 3.
2. This is not configurable in Python 2.x at all.

At this point, you have several options:

1. Fix the tool. Backport the fixes to 2.7, submit a patch, hope for inclusion.
2. Switch to Python 3, at least for this tool, or ideally for everything you do.
3. Use a better extraction tool.

I would recommend 3. There’s really no reason to use `pygettext` when `xgettext` from GNU gettext tool, which is *the* gettext extraction tool, fully supports Python. It also supports non-ASCII source code with the `--from-code` flag — just pass `--from-code=utf-8` to it.

Or don’t even bother and do the sources extraction entirely from Poedit. It always bundles the most recent gettext tools, directly supports this scenario (Catalog → Properties → Source code charset) and recognizes Python files with no extra configuration.

Comment: Thank you Václav. I am going to try your suggestions with poedit and gettex.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue
i want set charset=UTF-8 when making .pot file

i only find this solution 
don't edit .pot file ,let it keep 'charset=CHARSET'
but when you make .po file from .pot file  use args locale  fix it in .po file

using --from-code can make "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n" in .pot file
example:
`$xgettext --from-code=utf-8 app.py -o app.pot`

you can use `$locale -a` check your locale list
using --locale can make "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n" in .po file
example:
`＄msginit --no-translator --input=app.pot --locale=en_US.utf8 -o translations/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/app.po`
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084191/command-or-option-for-the-xgettext-msginit-msgfmt-sequence-for-setting-the-mim)

btw

if you very care about  charset=CHARSET in .pot file
you can try this way
example
`$xgettext --from-code=utf-8 app.py -o app.pot

$sed -i 's/charset=CHARSET/charset=UTF-8/g' app.pot`
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349175/charset-problem-with-xgettext-msgmerge)

Comment: [--from-code=name args](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html)

Comment: [--locale args](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msginit-Invocation.html)